# Change email headers in PHP pear mail

Tags: php, email, pear, email-headers

I need some help with my PHP. When I sent myself an email for a test, I can see the `Received: from localhost` in the header.

Here is what it show:

```
Received: from localhost ([107.191.96.136]) by appmaildev.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(8.5.9600.16384);
     Mon, 26 Nov 2018 20:13:27 +0000
Received: from localhost (gateway1.mydomain.com [104.128.226.35])
    by mail.mydomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id E30387B8AB8A
    for <test-296da7c1@appmaildev.com>; Mon, 26 Nov 2018 15:13:25 -0500 (EST)
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
Received: from mail.mydomain.com (gateway1.mydomain.com [104.128.226.35])
        by mail.mydomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id E30387B8AB8A
        for <test-296da7c1@appmaildev.com>; Mon, 26 Nov 2018 15:13:25 -0500 (EST)
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = "Chris <rob@mydomain.com>";
$to = "Rob Smith <test-29634da7c1@appmaildev.com>";
$subject = "Test email number 4";
$body = "Hey Ben,

I am writing to you that someone have told me you have receive my email in your inbox.

I am interested to know how you have done it exactly??

Please let me know how you did it.

Thanks,
Rob";


$host = "smtp.mydomain.com";
$port = "587";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";


$headers = array ('From' => $from, 
    'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject,
    'Reply-To' => $from,
    'Content-type' => 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n\r\n',
    'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
    'Date'  => date("r"),
    'Message-ID' => sprintf("<%s.%s@%s>",
            base_convert(microtime(), 10, 36),
            base_convert(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8)), 16, 36),
            'mydomain.com'));

$params = array ('host' => $host,
    'port' => $port,
    'auth' => 'PLAIN', // Note 1
    'socket_options' => array('ssl' => array('verify_peer_name' => false, 'verify_peer' => false)), // Note 2
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password);

$smtp = Mail::factory ('smtp', $params);
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
  echo("<p>Email has been sent!</p>");
}
?>
```

I am using pear php to send myself an email.

Do you know how I can change from `Received: from localhost` to `Received: from mail.mydomain.com`?

If so, can you please show me an example of what I should use to remove the localhost?

Comment: are you sending from localhost?

Comment: yes I sending from my web host using PHP. Are there anything I can do to remove localhost to replace it with `mail.mydomain.com`?

Comment: no that's the mail server setting that, you cant change it -- and why would you want to? only spammers do that

Answer (score 1):

From memory, the issue isn't with you're code, it's with locally hosted mail server you're using.

I had a similar issue a few years ago. What are the details (eg. is it local, what software package, etc).

What I did was tell the localhost to tell other servers it was (in your case) "mail.mydomain.com".

Comment: thank you for letting me to know. What did you do to change it from localhost to `mail.mydomain.com` through on the software?

Comment: Something like this [link]http://forums.msexchange.org/Can_I_change_host_name%3f/m_1800438542/tm.htm[link]